# Is there a way to export jcr:data submitted from a form?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I'm using AEM6 adaptive forms. The submit action for my form is `Forms Portal Submit Action`. Submitting a form this way saves the data for the form as an xml in the `jcr:data` property as shown in the image below

[image]

The data is saved like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><afData>
  <afUnboundData>
    <data>
      <GeneralInformation_guidetextbox>this is a test</GeneralInformation_guidetextbox>
      <GeneralInformation_guidetextbox_3>3013957578</GeneralInformation_guidetextbox_3>
      <GeneralInformation_guidetextbox_4>213650432</GeneralInformation_guidetextbox_4>
      <ServiceInformation_guidetextbox>some number</ServiceInformation_guidetextbox>
    </data>
  </afUnboundData>
  <afBoundData/>
</afData>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to export all the data under `/content/forms/fp/admin/submit/data/` and then import that data into another instance of AEM6?

I tried doing this through the Bulk Editor but I think its not meant for this type of thing.

Comment: can't you just create a CRX package, build it, download and upload&install on the other instance? Detailed info on using packages: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/how_to/package_manager.html

Comment: The other instance has existing data. I don't want to overwrite to that data but instead add-on to that data. downloading -> upload -> install of a CRX package would lose the data on the other instance, right?

Comment: you should play with the mode parameter within the filter file: http://www.wemblog.com/2012/04/how-to-change-package-install-behavior.html. You can either say that the changes should be merged (`mode=merge`) meaning no data will be altered on instance, only new nodes will be added or you can specifiy update mode where existing nodes will be altered only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize input data between instances, then probably [Reverse Replication](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/replication.html)is the way to go - long story short - it replicates (typically user-submitted) data from publish back to author, which in turn can then be published onto other publishes.